# Searching counts restriction and undefined search keywords

Tags: discussion, support, search

Can anyone explain me why [**Meta Search Page**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search) restricts search counts ?
I have no idea for limiting search counts and I don't expect as this..

[image]

> +**Addition**

I searched with some alphabets ***( a...z )*** . I found a strange thing. Finding with ***(b ... z )*** characters and

***( a )***
character was different. Please check as below..

[image]

```
Message show "Could not find any results......but showing results for a ...xxx".
I don't understand this message.
Why different for "a" character and why adding double code ("") in *a* ?
*a* is not a special character.
```

Comment: searching with character "a" will automatically add double code ("").

Comment: I assume restriction on searching counts 30 per a minute is needless.

Comment: I'm certain the 30 search in 60 seconds limit has ever been hit by anyone doing genuine searches. I imagine it's there because they don't want some bot(/misbehaving user) to fire off 10,000 search requests each minute.

Comment: I could not reproduce the limit, got this though: http://i.stack.imgur.com/7Ra5p.png thanks for forcing me to take a break from the site! ;)

Comment: by the way , searching page of meta site is so simple and so nice. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Can anyone explain me why Meta Search Page restricts search counts ?

To prevent bots from spamming it like crazy - *very* rarely would anyone doing legitimate search hits ever encounter this.

> ( a ) character was different.

`a` is a [stop word](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stop_words) and irrelevant as a token in almost every search - so it's discarded unless *explicitly* included which is what quoting it does.

Comment: yes ,really great. It is new for me . about English stopwords http://norm.al/2009/04/14/list-of-english-stop-words/

Comment: and I would like to request to you ! can you explain what is message means to (that I described as )?

Comment: but searching with "all" word. That was include in english-stopwords but not like as "a".

Comment: @Cataclysm I don't understand your question.  We're using a standard english stop word list that Lucene includes - for now that is.  elasticsearch 1.0 disables them by default, so that'll be interesting.

Comment: Due to "a" is containing in stop-words list , so it is discarded . If so I expect "all" word also discarded but not.

Comment: @Cataclysm "all" is not an irrelevant word most of the time, why would it be discarded?  Stop words are discarded because they add no value a very large majority of the time.

Answer (score 1):

The Letter `a` i think is on a "black list" like `is`, `of` or `on`, cause searching for these values results in the same message as for `a`.

So searches for words, that are on the "black list" are changed to an `exact search` (`"a"`) to reduce the amount of results.

Comment: yah... sure ! I think as so . I described as it is strange thing because b to z is ok . why not "a" ? :)

Comment: @Cataclysm Thats a good question. I think it is so, cause `a` is a valid englisch word, while the others (except `I`) are not. Searching for `i` does not result in that message.